# How to get images from instagram with in time interval with specific tag?

Tags: ios, objective-c, instagram

I am trying to get instagram images of specific tag with in time interval instead of filtering in app.

**For example i need images with hashtag CRICKET posted in time between Today 8 AM to Today 10 AM.**

Answer (score -1):

Please look at [instagram API](http://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/media/)

you can limit the time range by setting `MIN_TIMESTAMP` and `MAX_TIMESTAMP` parameters.

Comment: is MIN_TIMESTAMP and MAX_TIMESTAMP works with hashtag search?

Comment: I tried with MIN_TIMESTAMP and MAX_TIMESTAMP with hashtag search. But i am not getting images between two dates.

Comment: MIN_TIMESTAMP and MAX_TIMESTAMP only work with search, not with hashtag